# MySQL Using AND Statement

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I am having issues with this question:

> Find the cities that have direct (non-stop) flights to both Honolulu and Newark.

[image]

The answer should be Dallas, since its the only location that has destinations to both Honolulu and Newark. I'm trying to use the `AND` statement but it wont work.

```
SELECT FLIGHTS.source_city
FROM FLIGHTS
WHERE (FLIGHTS.destination_city = 'Honolulu') and (FLIGHTS.destination_city = 'Newark')
```

I am using MySQL.

Comment: This category of problems is called *relational division* and I'm tagging your question as such. Feel free to take a look at [other relational division questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relational-division).

Answer (score 1):

`FLIGHTS.destination_city`cannot be the same value at the same time, therefore a join of the same table for each destination reference is required like:

```
SELECT f1.source_city
FROM FLIGHTS f1
JOIN FLIGHTS f2 ON f1.source_city = f2.source_city
WHERE f1.destination_city = 'Honolulu'
  AND f2.destination_city = 'Newark'
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use AND. The construction `WHERE (FLIGHTS.destination_city = 'Honolulu') and (FLIGHTS.destination_city = 'Newark')` which you tries to use means that you want to find a record in which destination is both Honolulu and Newark IN THE SAME RECORD. Of course, it is impossible.

If the destinations count is strongly 2, the [danblack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack)'s [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229692/150107) seems to be optimal.

If the destinations count vary, you must use some another method.

For MySQL it is: select records, where destination is Honolulu **OR** Newark **OR** another city which you need, then count the number of unique destination cities in the filtered records for each separate source city, and select only records where this count is equal to the number of destination cities:

```
SELECT flights.source_city
FROM flights
WHERE flights.destination_city IN ('Honolulu', 'Newark', 'Midland')
GROUP BY flights.source_city
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT flights.destination_city) = 3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c248bf865fff1d7f2a3d7f465526cc4a)