# Select records with the same first column value and different second column value? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, query

Assume we have a SQL Server table as the following:

```
ContentId |  TagId
--------------------
1               2
1               3
2               1
2               2
2               3
1002            1
1002            1003
1003            4
1003            1002
1004            1
1005            2002
1006            1
1006            1003
1007            1
1007            1003
1008            2
1008            3
```

How can we select records with the same `ContentId` and `TagId` in 1, 1003.
In my sample result is as follows

```
ContentId |  TagId
----------------------
1002            1
1002            1003
1006            1
1006            1003
1007            1
1007            1003
```

Or

```
ContentId 
----------
1002                        
1006                        
1007
```

Comment: Look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229697/150107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could use intersect to get the matching records**

```
SELECT ContentId 
FROM dbo.Content
WHERE TagId = 1003
INTERSECT
SELECT ContentId 
FROM dbo.Content
WHERE TagId = 1;
```

**Result**

```
ContentId
1002
1006
1007
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ea2ff1899e46a50ab8a1a4eda546786)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
SELECT ct.ContentId
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM ContentTag AS ct
    WHERE ct.TagId IN (1, 1003)
) AS ct
GROUP BY ct.ContentId
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32ccec55bec5b93a21c534a0a7fbf53f